# HXT using 'orElse' to replace missing attribute value with default

Tags: xml, haskell, hxt

I am using HXT to parse a simple XML file and need to replace missing attributes of a tag with default value. But for some reason `orElse` does not work as expected.

Below is XML file:

```
<!-- window_home.xml -->
<elements>
  <Window libraryItemName="panel_tabs" name="panel_tabs" selected="true">
    <matrix>
      <Matrix ty="-11.8" />
    </matrix>
  </Window>
  <Window libraryItemName="home_powerup_menu" name="home_powerup_menu" selected="true">
    <matrix>
      <Matrix tx="12.4" />
    </matrix>
  </Window>
  <Window libraryItemName="panel_name" name="panel_name" selected="true">
    <!-- data here  -->
  </Window>
</elements>
```

Tag in question is `Matrix`.
Below is my code:

```
{-# LANGUAGE Arrows, NoMonomorphismRestriction #-}
import Text.XML.HXT.Core

parseXML = readDocument [ withValidate no
                        , withRemoveWS yes  -- throw away formating WS
                        ] 

atTag tag = deep (isElem >>> hasName tag)

data XflMatrix = XflMatrix { a, b, c, d, tx, ty :: Float } deriving (Show)
initXflMatrix = XflMatrix { a = 1.0, d = 1.0, b = 0.0, c = 0.0, tx = 0.0, ty = 0.0 }

data UiWindow = UiWindow {
    wndName :: String,
    wndNameLib :: String,
    wndMatrix :: XflMatrix,
    wndChildren :: [UiWindow]
    } deriving (Show)

initUiWindow = UiWindow {
    wndName = "empty",
    wndNameLib = "",
    wndMatrix = initXflMatrix,
    wndChildren = []
    }


parseDoc docName = runX $ parseXML fileName >>> getWindow
  where
    fileName = docName ++ ".xml"

getMatrixFromTag = atTag "Matrix" >>> proc x -> do
    tx <- getFloatAttrib "tx" -< x
    ty <- getFloatAttrib "ty" -< x
    returnA -< initXflMatrix { tx = read tx :: Float, ty = read ty :: Float }
        where
            --getFloatAttrib attribName = getAttrValue attribName
            getFloatAttrib attribName = getAttrValue attribName `orElse` constA "0.0"

getWindow = atTag "Window" >>> proc x -> do
    libraryItemName <- getAttrValue "libraryItemName" -< x
    name <- getAttrValue "name" -< x
    m <- getMatrixFromTag -< x
    children <- arrIO parseDoc -< libraryItemName
    returnA -< initUiWindow { wndName = name, wndNameLib = libraryItemName, wndChildren = children, wndMatrix = m}


documentName = "DOMDocument.xml"        

parseRoot = parseXML documentName
--runX (parseRoot >>> getWindow )
```

It looks like the line

```
getFloatAttrib attribName = getAttrValue attribName `orElse` constA "0.0"
```

Does not return `"0.0"`.

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, that was stupid.
I should have checked the types:

```
λ: :t getAttrValue
getAttrValue :: ArrowXml a => String -> a XmlTree String
λ: :t hasAttr
hasAttr :: ArrowXml a => String -> a XmlTree XmlTree
```

Now, after changing the line in question to:

```
getFloatAttrib attribName = (hasAttr attribName >>> getAttrValue attribName) `orElse` constA "0.0"
```

Everything is fine.